# IKEv2 VPN El Capitan 10.11

Tags: macos, network, vpn

When I setup an IKEv2 VPN, which I use from Windows without issues, on OSX 10.11.1 it refuses to connect.  I looked at /var/log/system.log and it seems like it's saying one of the IKEv2 components is missing.  Has anyone gotten a certificate authenticated IKEv2 connection working in OSX?  The VPN server is StrongSwan.

```
/var/log/system.log:Nov 27 09:16:09 Jeremiahs-MacBook-Pro nesessionmanager[608]: NESMIKEv2VPNSession[VPN (IKEv2):0EE0F0F7-F55C-4657-ABCB-9B51583F1D22]: Received a start command from com.apple.preference.network.re[868]
/var/log/system.log:Nov 27 09:16:09 Jeremiahs-MacBook-Pro nesessionmanager[608]: NESMIKEv2VPNSession[VPN (IKEv2):0EE0F0F7-F55C-4657-ABCB-9B51583F1D22]: status changed to connecting
/var/log/system.log:Nov 27 09:16:09 Jeremiahs-MacBook-Pro nesessionmanager[608]: Failed to find the VPN app for plugin type com.apple.neplugin.IKEv2
/var/log/system.log:Nov 27 09:16:09 Jeremiahs-MacBook-Pro neagent[2019]: Failed to process IKE SA Init packet
/var/log/system.log:Nov 27 09:16:09 Jeremiahs-MacBook-Pro nesessionmanager[608]: NESMIKEv2VPNSession[VPN (IKEv2):0EE0F0F7-F55C-4657-ABCB-9B51583F1D22]: status changed to disconnecting
/var/log/system.log:Nov 27 09:16:09 Jeremiahs-MacBook-Pro nesessionmanager[608]: NESMIKEv2VPNSession[VPN (IKEv2):0EE0F0F7-F55C-4657-ABCB-9B51583F1D22]: status changed to disconnected, last stop reason Stop command received
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late , but I did get this working.

In `ipsec.conf`, I had to update the ciphers and the rightauth. I'd prefer to use something better, but at the time it connects.

```
rightauth=eap-tls
ike=3des-sha1-modp1024
esp=3des-sha1-modp1024
```

BTW: even with connecting, I still get the above errors/warnings.

Update: I found that the mobileconfig profile needed for iOS can be used for OS X also, which will allow you to define and  update the encryption algorithm, integrity algorithm and diffiehellman group. You can read about all the config settings on [Apple's Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW613). It looks like you can max everything out at at AES-256/SHA2-512/18 (modp_8192)